# image upload ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

```
<form id="imageform" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action='path+controller'>


 $("#imageform").ajaxForm({
     target: '#preview'
 }).submit();
```

I am using ajax to upload an image file. It is running successfully.But i am facing issue with to get values after successfully uploaded.Want to get some values from backend in javascript variabe. As we get success on ajax call. Please revert me back as soon as possible.

Comment: please improve your subject and question.

Comment: @sumandeepkaur Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behaviour, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I want to know how to get ajax success while using jquery .ajaxForm()

Comment: $(“#imageform”).ajaxForm({ target: '#preview' }).submit().done(function( data ) { alert( “Data Loaded: ” + data ); }); using this code to upload an image file

Comment: I am trying to use .done() but in vain

Comment: $("#imageform").ajaxForm({
                        target: '#preview'
        }).submit(); this code is working perfectly.. Please tell me what to add in jquery or js to get values in valriable what i have echo in php file

Comment: The comment section is not a chat, and posting a lot will not make us answer faster (actually, quite the contrary). Edit your question, change your title, and update your question with the details provided in comments.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$("#imageform").ajaxForm({
target: '#preview',
data: {},
success: function() {
   alert("Callback!");
}
}).submit();
```